# Python extract information from paragraph

Tags: python, regex, text, text-extraction

I am new to Python and right now I am trying to extract information from a set of paragraphs containing employees related statistics.

For example, the paragraph might look like:

> Name Rakesh Rao Age 34 Gender Male Marital Status Single

The whole text is not separated by any comas so I am having a hard time separating this information.
Also sometimes there might be a colon after the name of the variable and sometimes there might not be. For example in row 1, it's `"Name Rakesh Rao"` but in row 2 it's `"Name: Ramachandra Deshpande"`.

There are around 1400 records of this information so it would be really great if I don't have to manually separate the information.
Can anyone help with this? I would be super grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I suppose you could try and do that using a regular expression.
If your text is exactly this:

```
paragraph = 'Name Rakesh Rao Age 34 Gender Male Marital Status Single'
```

You could use this regular expression (you would have to `import re` first):

```
m = re.fullmatch(
    (
    r'Name(?:\:)? (?P<name>\D+) '  # pay attention to the space at the end
    r'Age(?:\:)? (?P<age>\d+) '
    r'Gender(?:\:)? (?P<gender>\D+) '
    r'Marital Status(?:\:)? (?P<status>\D+)'  # no space here, since the string ends
    ),
    paragraph
)
```

Then you could use the names of the groups defined within the regular expression, like this:

```
>>> m.group('name')
'Rakesh Rao'
>>> m.group('age')
'34'
>>> m.group('gender')
'Male'
>>> m.group('status')
'Single'
```

If all the fields are in a single line, you just have to replace `\n` with a single space within the regular expression.

Note that this will support a single comma immediately after row name, like this:

```
Name: Rakesh Rao
```

but it will not support different order of the data. If you would like that as well, I could try to write a different expression.

#### Explanation of the expression

Let's take the first "line" of the expression:

```
r'Name(?:\:)? (?P<name>\D+) '
```

First, why the `r'…'` string syntax? This is just to avoid double backslashes. In the "typical" string, we would need to write the expression like this:

```
'Name(?:\\:)? (?P<name>\\D+) '
```

Now, to the actual expression. The first part, `Name`, is pretty obvious.

```
(?:\:)?
```

This part creates a non-capturing group (`(?:…)`) with a colon inside – it's `\:` and not just `:`, because the colon itself is part of a regex syntax. Non-capturing group, because this colon really doesn't matter to us.

Then, after a single space, we have this:

```
(?P<name>\D+)
```

This creates a named group, the syntax is `(?P<name_of_the_group>…)`. I use a named group just to make it easier and nicer to extract the information later, using `m.group('name')`, where `m` is a match object.

The `\D+` means "at least one non-digit character". This captures all letters, underscores, but also white spaces. That is why the order of the fields is so important to this particular expression. If you were to change the order and put `Gender` field between `Name` and `Age`, it would capture it as well, because the `+` modifier is greedy.

On the other hand, the `\d+` in the next "line" means "at least one digit character", so between 0 and 9.

I hope that explanation is enough, but it might be useful to you to play with that expression here, on this very useful site:

https://regex101.com/r/N5ZJU9/2

I've already entered the regex and the test string for you.

Comment: Man, you are insane! This is so powerful and exactly what I need. Thank you very very much!

Comment: I'm very happy to help! If I was right that the fields are on separate lines, would you mind editing the question to match this fact? Also, if you need an explanation of syntax of the expression that I wrote, I can add it to my answer as well.

Comment: Oh, the fields are actually together in the same paragraph. If you have time yes please help me with the syntax. Thanks!

Comment: I meant all the data is in the same line.

Comment: Done, I hope that this little explanation will be helpful for you.

Comment: You are the best! Thanks a lot and I learned so much from you!

Comment: May I ask what is the source of your data in this format? I'm a little worried that you might be falling into [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) (which, on the other hand, might be actually useful to you in a way, as mentioned in the comments to that linked answer).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! My original data is hand typed by other workers in excel. Each person's information is stored in one paragraph. I want to separate the information so I can make a proper spread sheet of personnel information.

Comment: You mean that: 1) each person is in one row in Excel; 2) columns in Excel for your example would look like: A — “Name”, B — “Rakesh Rao”, C — “Age”, D — “34”?

Comment: Never mind. Also I want to ask a few more questions, (which I already posted in another question I asked). If the capture group includes a combination of characters and numbers, (?P<name>\D+) doesn't seem to work. How should I deal with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can match optional characters, in your case it is `:` with the following expression `[:]?`.

According to the provided information, this regex should extract the required information:

```
^Name[:]?\s([A-Z][-'a-zA-Z]+)\s([A-Z][-'a-zA-Z]+)$
```

You can check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/ylQF6J/1/).
This regular expression will match two-words names. Also names containing `-'`.
In Python this may look like that:

```
regex = r"^Name[:]?\s([A-Z][-'a-zA-Z]+)\s([A-Z][-'a-zA-Z]+)$"    
test_str = ("Name Rakesh Rao\n"
    "Name: Ramachandra Deshpande")    
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
```

You can also check this example by the link provided above.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the field names are always in the string, you can split the string on those field names. For example:

```py
str_to_split = "Name Rakesh Rao Age 34 Gender Male Marital Status Single"
splitted = str_to_split.split("Age")
name = splitted[0].replace("Name", "")
```

If your text still contains other chars, you can remove them with `replace(":", "")` for instance. Otherwise you can use the NLTK toolkit to remove all kind of special chars from your text. Be careful, because names could also have special chars in them.